# ACF Image field not displaying in Wordpress with Visual Composer

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm creating a website for a client who wants to be able to add products to the site himself, in the most straight-forward manner possible.

To facilitate this, I thought I'd try ACF. So far, it all works. Apart from images.

I've set up ACF with the following parameters:

Field Group: Main Image
Field Name: main_image
Field Type: Image
Return value: Image URL

In Visual Composer, I've tried using the built-in ACF element, but it's not displaying the image.

I've also tried adding the following code to Visual Composer as both 'Raw HTML' and 'Text Box' in text mode (rather than visual mode):

```
<img src="<?php the_field('main_image'); ?>" alt="Product Image" />
```

Which doesn't display the image.

I've also tried that code using the Classic WP editor (in text view), but for some reason this covers the entire page in the site's background colour (although all the elements are still there using the Inspect tool).

I've watched online tutorials, read as much as I can on here, and I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write PHP code in the WordPress post editor screen. You can do this by editing the theme's template files (using an FTP client).
This means you need to write the entire structure of the page using HTML/PHP.

You could look into [making a shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). A shortcode enables you to execute a predefined piece of code (like: `get_field($handle);`)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Have gotten further with it now, but it's brought up another question which I'll post seperately.